# gateway using different subnet than router

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I'm installing a new router on a home network and the new router's routing table is as follows: 
[image]

The gateway shown here is the modem which used to also be used as a router. Now is this a problem that the gateway seems to follow completely different ip subnetting? Are there any disadvantages to this?

all connected devices on 192.168.0.X have no problems accessing the internet.

Comment: What's the make and model and of router? The gateway for the WAN is it's gateway I believe so when packets are destined for a subnet not on the LAN, it'll use that for the WAN gateway. The WAN is what routes to that IP as it's gateway and not the LAN side. When the LAN side connected machines need to use the router, the router will send to the WAN gateway if it cannot route otherwise without going out that gateway. Depending ont he make and model, I think that is what's going on. Routers/firewall usually have internal routing tables to route internally between different subnet interfaces too.

Comment: When connected on the LAN side, do you get a ping response from `10.0.0.138`. What is the gateway defined on a machine connected to the LAN network that does have access to the Internet. Use either `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` or maybe `ip a` to get some of that detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can the gateway IP be different then the IP of the router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1177137/can-the-gateway-ip-be-different-then-the-ip-of-the-router)

From the answer to this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/186645/does-default-gateway-ip-router-ip

> ```
> The "default gateway" is simply the IP of the next hop for traffic that is not explicitly routed anywhere else. This will, almost
> ```
>
> certainly, be an IP address on an interface of a local router.
>   However, it may not be an address on which you can manage the router.
>
> So, I suppose the answer could be "Yes", but in most networks is most
>   likely "No".
>
> Also, some Routers could have a different IP for management, but for
>   actual traffic if the Router is the next hop for that traffic, the
>   Router and Gateway IP would be the same.

I wasn't positive so had to find a few references.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the external side of the router is connected to your ISP, the Gateway IS external. It need to be this way to help manage traffic in and out of your router.

If the router is somehow internal, use the other side of the router for gateway.

Comment: no this gateway ip is the internal ip. If the modem is used as a router the local network is 10.0.0.X

Comment: Use the other side of the router for the gateway address